# What is the probability of matching color pens with the right color cap?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Suppose I have $10$ pens each with caps of the matching color:

- 4 red
- 3 blue
- 2 black
- 1 green

If I mix the caps and pair them with the pens randomly, what is the expected number of resulting pens whose caps have the matching color?

Comment: @David G. Stork: This edit seems like a different question from the one the OP asked.  It *might* be what the OP intended, but that seems far from clear to me.  Maybe OP could clarify what is meant here?

Comment: Here is why I made the edit.  "What is the probability of matching color pens with the right color cap?" is ambiguous.  As stated, the probability might refer to:  "the probability of matching *some* color pens with their right color cap."  Imagine some setup involving 10 total pens (colored somehow) in which every possible random case had *at least one* pen/cap match.  Then the stated probability would be interpreted as 100%.  Focusing on the expected number of matches seems the proper way to focus on the probability that *any individual pen* matches its cap... which is what the OP wants.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: In my opinion, until OP clarifies their intent, the question is ambiguous (as you point out).  It could read as you've interpreted it, but it could also legitimately be asking for $P(\text{all pens match their cap})$.  Both seem plausible to me, so it should rest with the OP to clarify their intent.

Comment: @tps: Please either confirm that David G. Stork has accurately captured your intent, or edit to clarify.  As your original post stood, the question was ambiguous.

Comment: @David G. Stork  Thanks for the edit. I agree that it was ambiguous. Indeed, what I need to know is the expected number of  caps with matching cap color!

Comment: @tps Welcome to the site. If any of the answers were helpful to you, you should click the green checkmark by the one you found the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a random variable for each pen. In particular $ X_i = 1$ if the color matches and $ X_i = 0$ otherwise.
We want to evaluate $$ \mathbb{E}[ X_1 + \ldots + X_{10}] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} \mathbb{E}[X_i] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} \mathbb{P}(X_i = 1)$$
Since:

- $ \mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = \frac{4}{10}$ if $1 \leq i \leq 4$
- $ \mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = \frac{3}{10}$ if $5 \leq i \leq 7$
- $ \mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = \frac{2}{10}$ if $8 \leq i \leq 9$
- $ \mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = \frac{1}{10}$ if $i=10$

the result is $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{4} j \cdot \frac{j}{10} = 3$

Comment: Where have you used the fact that there are different numbers of pens of a given color?  Surely if all pens/caps were the same color, the expected number would be $10$.  If the pens/caps came in $10$ different colors the answer would be much smaller.  Given the $4, 3, 2, 1$ distribution, the answer will be yet different.  You haven't answered the question as asked.

Comment: I will try to be more clear then, editing my previous post

Comment: Your error is explicit in your final equation where you somehow think the probability a given cap matches a pen's color is $1/10$, which may be true for green, but it is false for the other $9$ pens/caps.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If there are $n$ pens total, and there are $c_j$ pens in the $j^{th}$ color, you would agree the correct answer would be $\sum_{j=1}^k c_j\cdot \frac{c_j}{n}$, yes? As there are $c_j$ pens whose probability of having a match is $\frac{c_j}n$? Well, here there are $j$ pens in the $j^{th}$ color, so $c_j=j$, resulting in exactly the formula they wrote! You should try a little harder to understand someone's answer before downvoting, especially if they are a new user.

Comment: I've edited my post, is it clear now? I am sorry if it wasn't before. But I've to say I have never thought it was $\frac{1}{10}$, and it was, in my humble opinion, clear even from my original post.

Comment: Note that the title and the question body have a mismatch.  The title is asking for $p(\sum_i X_i = 10)$ whereas the question body asks for $E(\sum_i X_i)$.  This answer addresses the question body.

Answer (score 1):

The original question was

> What is the probability of matching pens and caps of the same color?

before David Stork edited the question, changing it to asking for the expected value.

The answer to the original question is
$$
\frac{4!\cdot 3!\cdot 2!\cdot 1!}{10!}
$$
This is because there are $10!$ equally likely assignments of pens to caps, but in a valid arrangement, there are $4!$ ways to assign red caps to red pens, $3!$ ways to assign blue caps to blue pens, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not fond of that edit.  I wonder what the right protocol is here.  I don't want to roll back the edit just in case that is what the OP intended, but that's far from clear.

Comment: @BrianTung I would want to roll back, because OP's original wording is most likely to be the closest to their intention, but I do not want to invalidate LucaMac's great answer.